# How to use servlet and jsp with authentication?

Tags: jsp, authentication, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm using Eclipse IDE with tomcat 7.0.

I have a web application, now in the web application I have:

1. `MainPage.html`
2. `Servlet1` (java class)
3. Some jsp files. (some of them are only for administrator - for example, `driving_page.jsp`)

In the main page, i have 4 buttons inside a form that redirect to the servlet.
When i click on one button, it goes to the servlet, the servlet redirect to `driving_page.jsp` but first it needs to show the `login.jsp` page and it didn't..

In chrome, i entered the driving_page URL as `localhost:8080/TaxiWeb/driving_page.jsp`
and before it display the page, it show me the '`login.jsp` page as it needs to be.

But if i click on the button in the `MainPage.html` which mentioned above, it skips on the `login.jsp` page and go directly to `driving_page.jsp` page. 
WHY?

**NOTE:** the `driving_page.jsp` file is inside the FOLDER:AdminPages..
      so the `url-pattern` in the `web.xml` file is correct.

`tomcat-users.xml:`

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>  
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

`my web.xml file:`

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Driving page</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/AdminPages/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>role1</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-role><role-name>role1</role-name></security-role>

  <login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/login_error.jsp</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
  !-- ********************************************************************** -->
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>pack.servlets.servlet1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/Servlet1</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

and the servlet code:
NOTE: i just add the mentioned button code in the servlet:

```
    else if (request.getParameter("submit").equals("Show Taxis at Driving"))
{
   request.getRequestDispatcher("AdminPages/driving_page.jsp").forward(request,response);
}
```

Comment: so my question is how to forward servlet to secured jsp?
because i need to send some data from the servlet to the jsp..

Comment: I suspect! somewhere your code invalidate the *session*.

Comment: @AVD, I didn't use Session. I have a login.jsp page and in this page
I have a form. the Action of the form is J_SECURITY_CHECK, so the security constraints need to redirect the user to the login page 
when he want to access to secure page. if he type the username and the password correct it needs to redirect him to the desired page.
Right now when I click the button to access to secured page, It skips the login page and directly goes to the secured page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem falls under the [servlet spec 13.2](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) (Declarative Security)

> The security model applies to the static content part of the web
> application and to servlets and filters within the application that
> are requested by the client.The security model does not apply when a
> servlet uses the RequestDispatcher to invoke a static resource or
> servlet using a forward or an include.

Basically your security constraint only gets picked up by the initial request and ignored by your servlet forward.

A fix for this would be to move all your secure JSP's under the WEB-INF folder so they can not be accessed directly. Update your forward paths to there. Then point your security constraints to cover your servlet rather than the JSP.

Comment: thanks i'll try it! but isn't the WEB-INF folder is 
to declare the web application info? like the web heirarchy?
right now, all the pages, the regular jsp, the html page and the login
pages are located in the 'WebContent' folder, and the admin jsp pages located in 'WebContent/AdminPages/" folder..

Comment: Sure, but the key point is that anything under the WEB-INF folder isn't publicly available. So if you want to prevent users from having direct access to your files, you put them there as well. Your code/servlets would still have access to them.

Comment: ok, so if i put the secured pages in the WEB-INF folder, so when
the user click on a button that redirect to some secured page, 
it will display first the login page?

Comment: Hi Sean, I did what you said, but when I point the security constraints to cover the servlet I'm getting an exception.
The servlet path is : Java Resources/src/pack.servlets/servlet1.java

so what u said is to change the url pattern to 
<url-pattern>Java Resources/src/pack.servlets/servlet1.java</url-pattern> right? but this cause to exception

Comment: you are pointing to the source folder of your servlet. you want it to cover the URL that the servlet refers to. in your case /Servlet1 (or possibly /Servlet1/* you will have to test it). much like before where you covered the folder for your admin JSP's.

Comment: so what i need to do is to move the secure jsp's to the WEB-INF folder, then in the security-constraints, change the url-pattern
to: /servlet1 or /servlet1/* and in the servlet code forward to 
"/WEB-INF/some_secured_page.jsp , is it right?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! it works fine! but now the login page appeard before all the pages, include the non-secured paged, so 
is it good idea to create another servlet that will handle the non-secure pages?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to use `response.sendRedirect(String location)`.This method sends back the response to the browser along with the status code and new page location. Now, browser again sends a new request for the redirected "location".
Here, you need to have a `Filter` on that URL and with in that filter, you need to check whether the user is allowed to view this page or not.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But I'm using the forward method because I need to pass parameters
to those jsp pages. And by the way, I have a login page, within 
this page i a form and the action of this form is "J_SECURITY_CHECK'